# Letsencrypt / nginx : SSL configuration went wrong

Tags: ssl, nginx, lets-encrypt

I recently acquired a domain name that I want to point to my home server. It worked very well before I tried to implement SSL. Since then I get this error when I try to access https://cloud.mydomain.com/:

```
SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG
```

I don't know how to debug on this at all.

With my host here is my config:

```
mydomain.com.   A [my external IP]

cloud.mydomain.com.   CNAME mydomain.com.
```

On my server I have this:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
    multi_accept on;
    use epoll;
}

http {
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    upstream php-handler {
        server unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
    }

    set_real_ip_from 127.0.0.1;
    set_real_ip_from 192.168.1.0/24;
    real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
    real_ip_recursive on;
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

    # include /etc/nginx/proxy.conf;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Protocol $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_connect_timeout 3600;
        proxy_send_timeout 3600;
        proxy_read_timeout 3600;
        proxy_redirect off;

    # include /etc/nginx/ssl.conf;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem;
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    # include /etc/nginx/header.conf;
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains; preload;";
        add_header X-Robots-Tag none; 
        add_header X-Download-Options noopen;
        add_header X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies none;
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
        add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
        add_header Referrer-Policy "no-referrer" always;
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";

    # include /etc/nginx/optimization.conf;
        fastcgi_hide_header X-Powered-By;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 3600;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 3600;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 3600;
        fastcgi_buffers 64 64K;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 256k;
        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 3840K;
        fastcgi_cache_key $http_cookie$request_method$host$request_uri;
        fastcgi_cache_use_stale error timeout invalid_header http_500;
        fastcgi_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires Set-Cookie;
        gzip on;
        gzip_vary on;
        gzip_comp_level 4;
        gzip_min_length 256;
        gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private no_last_modified no_etag auth;
        gzip_types application/atom+xml application/javascript application/json application/ld+json application/manifest+json application/rss+xml application/vnd.geo+json application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf application/x-web-app-manifest+json application/xhtml+xml application/xml font/opentype image/bmp image/svg+xml image/x-icon text/cache-manifest text/css text/plain text/vcard text/vnd.rim.location.xloc text/vtt text/x-component text/x-cross-domain-policy;
        gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.";


    default_type application/octet-stream;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
    sendfile on;
    send_timeout 3600;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    open_file_cache max=500 inactive=10m;
    open_file_cache_errors on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    reset_timedout_connection on;
    server_tokens off;
    resolver 192.168.1.1 valid=30s;
    resolver_timeout 5s;

    # include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

        # etc/nginx/conf.d/nextcloud.conf;
        server {
            server_name cloud.mydomain.com;
            listen 80 default_server;
            listen [::]:80 default_server;

            location / {
                return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
            }
        }

        server {
            server_name cloud.mydomain.com;
            listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
            listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
            root /var/www/nextcloud/;

            location = /robots.txt {
                allow all;
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
            }

            location = /.well-known/carddav {
                return 301 $scheme://$host/remote.php/dav;
            }

            location = /.well-known/caldav {
                return 301 $scheme://$host/remote.php/dav;
            }

            #SOCIAL app enabled? Please uncomment the following row
            #rewrite ^/.well-known/webfinger /public.php?service=webfinger last;
            #WEBFINGER app enabled? Please uncomment the following two rows.
            #rewrite ^/.well-known/host-meta /public.php?service=host-meta last;
            #rewrite ^/.well-known/host-meta.json /public.php?service=host-meta-json last;

            client_max_body_size 10240M;

            location / {
                rewrite ^ /index.php;
            }

            location ~ ^/(?:build|tests|config|lib|3rdparty|templates|data)/ {
                deny all;
            }

            location ~ ^/(?:\.|autotest|occ|issue|indie|db_|console) {
                deny all;
            }

            location ^~ /apps/rainloop/app/data {
                deny all;
            }

            location ~ \.(?:flv|mp4|mov|m4a)$ {
                mp4;
                mp4_buffer_size 100M;
                mp4_max_buffer_size 1024M;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?.php)(\/.*|)$;
                set $path_info $fastcgi_path_info;
                try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;
                include fastcgi_params;
                include php_optimization.conf;
            }

            location ~ ^\/(?:index|remote|public|cron|core\/ajax\/update|status|ocs\/v[12]|updater\/.+|oc[ms]-provider\/.+).php(?:$|\/) {
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?.php)(\/.*|)$;
                set $path_info $fastcgi_path_info;
                try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;
                include fastcgi_params;
                include php_optimization.conf;
            }

            location ~ ^\/(?:updater|oc[ms]-provider)(?:$|\/) {
                try_files $uri/ =404;
                index index.php;
            }

            location ~ .(?:css|js|woff2?|svg|gif|map|png|html|ttf|ico|jpg|jpeg)$ {
                try_files $uri /index.php$request_uri;
                access_log off;
                expires 360d;
            }
        }
}
```

Here is the command I ran to generate the certificates:

`sudo certbot --nginx -d mydomain.com -d cloud.mydomain.com`

Note that when I access it from the local network with the address of the machine I have the certificate and the nextcloud is displayed.

My router is configured to transfer calls `80` and `443` on my machine and I can see the logs on `/var/log/nginx/access.log`

When I run the command:

```
openssl s_client -connect cloud.mydomain.com:443 -servername mydomain.com
```

I have the following result:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
140509444985920:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:../ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:332:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 5 bytes and written 317 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

Would you know how to debug this please?

Comment: This is a typical sign that you try to access a site with `https://` which has no `https:// enabled. Are you sure that you actually forward external port 443 to your server on port 443 and not to port 80? Also, check the error log of your server for more information of what might be wrong.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich thank you so much ! You're right. I had misconfigured my router... Both port 80 and port 443 were redirected to the machine's 80.